# Copy 1-hour-old files from another machine

Tags: bash, scp

I have this part in my script where I would copy files from another machine to the current machine running.

`scp user@samplemachine:/home/user/test/* /home/user/test`

But then I should only copy files created 1 hour ago. How can I achieve this? Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Since you are copying files from remote machine, you need to first identify files changed in remote location. Try `find /home/user/test -mmin -60` on remote location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should combine `scp` with `find` to get this to work.

First list the files on the remote server that are older than 1 hour:

```
ssh user@samplemachine find /home/user/test -type f -mmin +60
```

and then use it in combination with `scp`:

```
scp user@samplemachine:`ssh user@samplemachine find /home/user/test -type f -mmin +60` /home/user/test
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Tobías but why is it that whenever there are multiple files to be copied, it always prompt the message `cp: cannot stat '/home/user/test/<filename>': No such file or directory`?

Comment: Check the output of `shh ... find...`, and permissions in both sides. Currently I'm using this without any problem.

Comment: I can only copy the first file returned by the `ssh.. find..` then it would return the `cp: cannot stat` message right after copying the first file. Here is the permission of the files to be copied: `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: Do you have filenames with spaces? Or other characters that must be escaped?

Comment: There are no filenames with spaces and other characters to be escaped yet I don't know why it wont work. I even tried adding `-r` to `scp` yet same results.

Comment: It's really strange, I can't imagine why it isn't working. Can you edit your question and post the result of `find` command, the exact full error of `cp: ...` and the `ls -l` of origin and target dirs? With all the data, maybe someone can explain us why it fails